# Spring boot Liquibase table created Postgres quote problems

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

I have created the tables using each purse Liquibase, but in the Postgres the tables come with quotes, what can I do?

```
 SELECT * FROM public."LabelEntity" //this is my postgres table name
```

How can I create tables without quotes?

**Application.yml**

```
spring:
 profiles:
   active: local
 liquibase:
   enabled: true
   url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/liquebase
   user: postgres
   password: 12345
   change-log: classpath:/db/liquibase/db.changelog-master.yml
 datasource:
   driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
 r2dbc:
   url: r2dbc:pool:postgresql://localhost:5432/liquebase
   username: postgres
   password: 12345

server:
  port: 8085
```

**Main changelog yaml**

```
 databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
     file: db/liquibase/create-label_entity-table.yml
```

**create-label_entity-table.yml**

```
  databaseChangeLog:

-  changeSet:
     id: 4
     author: zaur
    changes:
     -  createTable:
          tableName: LabelEntity
          columns:
            -  column:
                 name: id
                 type: serial
                 autoIncrement: true
                 constraints:
                   primaryKey: true
                   nullable: false
            -  column:
                 name: name
                 type: varchar(255)
            -  column:
                 name: color
                 type: int
                 constraints:
                   nullable: false
            -  column:
                 name: orderdata
                 type: int
            -  column:
                 name: favorite
                 type: boolean
```

Comment: Can you show your liquibase files please

Comment: There is no file that creates LabelEntity

Comment: Don't use mixed case - liquibase then uses double quotes to preserve that. Use `tableName: label_entity` instead

Comment: Thanks for help me a_horse_with_no_name